# VB6 Registry Key Value Problem

Tags: vb6, registry, key, edit

Within VB6 I have used the following code to add to Registry,

```
Dim x As Object
x = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
x.RegWrite "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell", "MADNESS"
```

It creates a key, however in the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

Instead of:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because you have a 64-bit OS and you're running a 32-bit (x86) application which is handled by Windows'"Windows On Windows" (WOW) feature. Basically, it allows you to run an x86 program on an x64 Windows OS. x86 programs usually have their own registry key structure (ie. the `Wow6432Node`) and their own program files folder (ie. `Program Files (x86)`). You can try using something like [this](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=1519) which uses WinAPI hooks. This may allow you to bypass the issue and write directly to the key you want. Though, I'm not sure if Windows has security measures in place that prevent x86 applications to write to x64 parts of the registry. (I can't see why it would.)

Answer (score 0):

You can shell `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe` which is the x64 version.

FYI: The x86 version is `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe`

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would stop using WScript.Shell and switch to this registry access class: http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=70915&lngWId=1

It's a little confusing to use at first, but it's solid and provides built-in support for accessing 64-bit registry entries rather than the re-directed Wow6432Node. You can do so simply by setting the desired access in the *.Path* method of the class. Here's an untested example:

```
Dim objRegistry as New UniRegistry
Dim objHKLMStartup as New UniRegistry

Set objHKLMStartup = objRegistry.Path([hKey Local Machine], "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", [Registry: Read] + [Registry: WOW64 64-bit])
```

You can then use a **For Each *variant* In objHKLMStartup** to extract any/all values in the given registry path.